# Hiding button on sucessful login or signup

Tags: swift, swift4.2

I have two screen A and B.

In screen A I have one `UIBarButtonItem` which is used for login/signup.

By pressing that button new popup will open with login and signup view.

Now I need to hide the button login/signup button on Screen A on successful signup or login in Screen B which was displayed as popup.

For now I have dismissed the screen B on successful signin / signup and on next launch of app the button is hidden.

I have used this on screen A to hide the button.

```
if(currentUser != nil) {
    loginRegisterButton.isHidden = true
}else {
    loginRegisterButton.isHidden = false
}
```

This only works on next app launch.
What I want is on the successful dismiss of screen B.

Comment: Add this code in viewWillAppear method

Comment: @RajeshKumarR it didn't work becoz the screen B is presented as popop i.e. screen A is not yet dismissed. so on the dismiss of screen B screen A is not reloaded. it was just there

Comment: Show the code. How are you presenting the screen B

Comment: If it's a pop up viewWillAppear will not 100% called it has to do with the way that he handles the pop up

Comment: @JackNelda You can use _delegation pattern_

Answer (score 0):

You can pass as a parameter the view controller that has the UIBarButton item from the first view controller to the view that handles the login and on successful login hide from the view the button that exists in the initial view controller. Ex.

```
class FirstVC: UIViewController {
    var barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem?

//    ...

func presentPopUp() {
    let popUp = PopUpView()
    //Configure PopUpView class that handles the login
    popUp.parentViewController = self
}
}

class PopUpView: UIView {
    var parentViewController: FirstVC?

func login() {
    // If successfull
    parentViewController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass delegate callback from `ViewControllerB` to `ViewControllerA`

**Delegate Protocol:**

```
protocol ViewControllerBDelegate {
   func loginSuccess(user: YOUR_CURRENT_USER_OBJECT_TYPE)
}
```

**In ViewControllerB:**

```
var delegate: ViewControllerBDelegate?
```

after successful registration

```
self.delegate?.loginSuccess(user: YOUR_CURRENT_USER_OBJECT_VALUE)
```

**In ViewControllerA:**

```
extension ViewControllerA: ViewControllerBDelegate {
   func loginSuccess(user: YOUR_CURRENT_USER_OBJECT_TYPE) {
     currentUser = user
   }
}
```

**While open viewcontrollerB:**

```
let controller = ViewControllerB(nibName: "ViewControllerB", bundle: nil)
controller.delegate = self 
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: false)
```

Comment: In ViewControllerB  i have two container i.e. for login and signup. what should i use to this code. ````let controller = ViewControllerB(nibName: "ViewControllerB", bundle: nil)
controller.delegate = self 
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: false)````

Comment: My ViewControllerB is presented modally with presentation : over current context and transition crossDissolve